# How to validate an integer with python that needs to be used in calculations

Tags: python, validation

I'm trying to validate that a user input int is numbers only. This has been my most recent try:

```
while True:

    NumCars = int(input("Enter the number of cars on the policy: "))
    NumCarsStr = str(NumCars)
    if NumCarsStr == "":
        print("Number of cars cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")
    elif NumCarsStr.isalpha == True:
        print("Number of cars must be numbers only. Please re-enter.")
    else:
        break
```

With this, I get the following error:

```
line 91, in <module>
    NumCars = int(input("Enter the number of cars on the policy: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
```

(I entered a "g" to test if it was working)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the input as a _string_, do whatever checks you want on that, _then_ try to cast it as integer. Also `NumCarsStr.isalpha` will _never_ be `== True`. You need to _call_ the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: This does not solve the issue if determining if a value passed is an integer. There are many characters that are both not a-z and not integers; typically symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Use try / except, and then break the loop if no exception is raised, otherwise capture the exception, print an error message and let the loop iterate again

```
while True:
    try:
        NumCars = int(input("Enter the number of cars on the policy: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an integer number")
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but presumably because you ignore OP's desired functionality of `print("Number of cars cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")`?

Comment: I'm answering the question:  `I'm trying to validate that a user input int is numbers only`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions! Unfortunately none of these answers did quite what I wanted to do, but they did lead me down a thought process that DID work.

```
 while True:

        NumCars = (input("Enter the number of cars on the policy: "))
        if NumCars == "":
            print("Number of cars cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")
        elif NumCars.isdigit() == False:
            print("Number of cars must be numbers only. Please re-enter.")
        else:
            break
```

After changing the NumCars input to a string, I validated with isdigit, and then when I needed the variable for the calculations, I converted it to integers at the instances where the variable would be used for calculations.

I don't know if it was the easiest or fastest way of doing this, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

`if type(input) == int: do_code_if_is_numbersonly() else:  print("Numbers Only")`

This checks the type of the input, and if it is integer (number) it does example code, otherwise it prints Numbers Only. This is a quick fix but in my opinion it should work well.

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize the .isnumeric() function to determine if the string represents an integer.

e.g;

```py
    NumCarsStr = str(input("Enter the number of cars on the policy: "))
    ...
    ...
    elif not NumCarsStr.isnumeric():
        print("Number of cars must be numbers only. Please re-enter.")
```

Comment: This doesn't address OP's problem at all

Comment: it actually addresses the problem partially,  but it allows decimal numbers which shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: isnumeric does not, in fact, allow decimal numbers. Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp

Comment: then the method name is chosen poorly. should be named `isDigit()`  I would expect a method named `isNumeric()` return true for  "-56.7". Basically anything castable to a float should be true,